# Magento SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have 2 sites, 1 upgraded to 1.7.0.2  and the other is fresh install 1.7.0.2
the both sites have this issue when working on attributes adding or deleting.
what shall I do and which piece of code I have to check?

Comment: This really needs a bit more information. For instance the code/query which resulted in the error.

Answer (score 0):

To enable PDO MySQL Debug need to edit this file: /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

```
protected $_debug               = true;
```

then we open this file: /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php, and replace this line about 234:

```
throw new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($e->getMessage(), (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
```

with this code:

```
$msg = "SQL ERROR: ". $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            $msg .= "SQL QUERY:" . $this->_stmt->queryString."\n";
            if(!empty($params)) {
                $msg .= "SQL PARAMS: ('". implode("','", $params) ."')\n";
            }
            $dbsEx = new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($msg, (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
            throw $dbsEx;
```

so now we will get a folder /var/**debug**/, and file **pdo_mysql.log** in this file we have now full mysql error with full mysql query. you can easily execute those failing queries in phpmyadmin or edit database table, params, etc.